# Prompting for password su - oracle -c "uptime"

Tags: linux

Trying to do some automation but when running the command its asking for password:

```
[non-root-user@XXXXXXXX ~]$ su - oracle -c "uptime"
Password:
```

or

```
[non-root-user@XXXXXXXX ~]$ sudo su - oracle -c "uptime"
[sudo] password for non-root-user:
```

What changes required that it should not go for password?

Comment: You can configure that in /etc/sudoers (only edit with the `visudo` command)

Comment: i can do sudo to oracle normally from that user , but need to run script by that way

Comment: `sudo -u oracle <yourcommand>`

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `su` with `sudo` to run another command.

You need a `NOPASSWD` entry in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
non-root-user       ALL = (oracle) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/uptime
```

And then you run:

```
sudo -u oracle uptime
```

Comment: ya its working , but if i am trying to place any script like abc.ksh thats not working .. could you please guide.

Comment: @Arya Do you consider that a useful problem description?